# Groupby: get the max value and keep all columns related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows:

[image]

For each column `objectid`, iam trying to keep the row for which the column `pct` is max.

I have done a groupby as follows:

```
df.groupby(['objectid'])['pct'].max().reset_index()
```

However, the issue is that i lose the information of other columns which i need to do other stuff.

here is an example of the output. The output only keeps two columns `objectid` and `pct`. However, i need all columns.

```
    objectid    pct
0   10000Aga    100.0
1   10001Aga    100.0
```

How can i do a groupy and retrieve the information of all columns.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `idx = df.groupby('objectid')['pct'].idxmax()` and then `result = df.loc[idx]`.

Comment: I get an error as follows: `KeyError: '[9999, 10000, 10001, ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values by `pct` and then keep the last one for each `objectid`.

If you want to use `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values("pct").groupby("objectid").last().reset_index()
```

Or you can use `dropduplicates`, which is faster:

```
df = df.sort_values("pct").drop_duplicates(["objectid"], keep="last")
```